# How to synchronize users in django rest api with Auth0

Tags: django, angular, django-rest-framework, jwt, auth0

I use Angular 2 as frontend, django rest framework as backend.

At frontend I use Auth0 for authenticating user (https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/angular2 ). and after I send the idtoken to my backend for creating news users (https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/backend/python connected auth0
the code in angular 2:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Auth }      from './auth.service';
import { AuthHttp }  from 'angular2-jwt';
import { Http }      from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Component({
  selector: 'ping',
  templateUrl: 'app/ping.template.html'
})

export class PingComponent {
  API_URL: string = 'http://localhost:8000/callback/';
  message: string;

  constructor(private auth: Auth, private http: Http, private authHttp: AuthHttp) {}

// the code for sending idtoken to my backend
//correct me please if    I am wrong
  public securedPing() {

    this.message = '';
    this.authHttp.post(`${this.API_URL}`,localStorage.getItem('id_token'))
      .map(res => res.json())
      .subscribe(
        data => this.message= data.text,
        error => this.message = error._body || error
      );
  }
};
```

and here the code of my backend in Django :

```
 from django.http import Http404

    from rest_framework.views import APIView
    from rest_framework.response import Response
    from rest_framework import status
    from django.http import JsonResponse
    from places_management.serializers import UserSerializer
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
    import jwt

    class Callbacks(APIView):
        authentication_classes = []
        permission_classes = []

        def authenticate(error):

            return Response(error,401)

        def post(self, request, format=None):
            """
            Callback for after user logs in. It creates a
            django auth user if one does not exist, username is the
            user_id retured frrom auth0
            """
            #token = request.META['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'].split('JWT ')[1]
            auth = request.META.get('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION', None)

            if not auth:
                return Response({'code': 'authorization_header_missing', 'description': 'Authorization header is expected'},status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)

            parts = auth.split()

            if parts[0].lower() != 'bearer':
                return authenticate({'code': 'invalid_header', 'description':     'Authorization header must start with Bearer'})
            elif len(parts) == 1:
                return authenticate({'code': 'invalid_header', 'description':     'Token not found'})
            elif len(parts) > 2:
                return authenticate({'code': 'invalid_header', 'description': 'Authorization header must be Bearer + \s + token'})

            token = parts[1]
            try:
                payload = jwt.decode(
                    token,
                    'Z-HWF9cDxGTk7aMZe0A2Ygt81vGBPihz1FCRzJfS87B0mCw1ClQzp1HgA7U3WsSg',
                    audience='GwtnxdwhMWsuGz6JxabDkrNvFhAvn5ZJS'
                    )
            except jwt.ExpiredSignature:
                return authenticate({'code': 'token_expired', 'description': 'token is expired'})
            except jwt.InvalidAudienceError:
                return authenticate({'code': 'invalid_audience', 'description': 'incorrect audience, expected: GwtnxdwhMWsuGz6JxabDkrNvFhvn5ZJS'})
            except jwt.DecodeError:
                return authenticate({'code': 'token_invalid_signature', 'description': 'token signature is invalid'})

            #try:
                #payload = settings.JWT_AUTH['JWT_DECODE_HANDLER'](token)
            #except:
                #return Response('text',status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)

            user = User.objects.filter(username=payload['sub']).first()
            if(user is None):
                password = User.objects.make_random_password()
                user = User.objects.create_user(
                    username=payload['sub'], password=password)

            serializer = UserSerializer(user, context={'user': user})
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Maybe I am wrong, please help

Answer (score 3):

<sub>As usual in software development there's more than one way to approach a given problem and the most suitable solution usually requires delving into a lot of small details.</sub>

However, there are a few things that are safe to say based on the information you shared. If you're leveraging Auth0 for use authentication you should not then be creating users in your back-end with passwords. Passwords are for authentication and you delegated that part, which is a good thing, as it's less work for you.

Having said that it's completely normal to still have some kind of per-user storage associated with your application, for example, to store user-specific application settings or other user owned data.

For this you'll have to store that data in association with a user identifier that can be safely used to identify the same user across multiple authentication sessions. That identifier should be the `sub` claim value contained within the ID Token given that per specification that value is stable and will allow you to identify recurring users when they complete the authentication through Auth0.

**In conclusion**, you back-end should not create new user identities as that is within the scope of authentication which is handled by Auth0; instead you should store data in association with a user identifier that allows you to continuously identify recurring users.

Comment: I totally agree with you but how I retrieve this Id user? When I send post file from angular2 , my Python server response is ok but in front I get a error message wich is [object progress event] . The server doesn't send me any of error I defined in my code. Maybe my angular post method is wrong. Please if Someone could do a angularfire2 and django sample to retrieve user ID from auth0, it Would be great. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Please Refer , It do contain full demo of Rest Api With JWT, Auth() , Api Integrated in front end with angular(1) js

https://github.com/rmemon/Angular-JS-django-rest-framework-jwt

Comment: please read. I mean Angular 2 and Auth0. could you help with Auth0 and django backend

Comment: I only recommendabout Auth in django User model with rest API-- Thanks Rahil